# Inconsistent TitleBar Height returns

Tags: c#, uwp, height, titlebar

Long story short, I tried to run this particular code

```
CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
dragarea.Height = coreTitleBar.Height;
HamBut.Margin = new Thickness(0, dragarea.Height, 0, 0);
Window.Current.SetTitleBar(dragarea);
```

When I run it on the first time, `coreTitleBar.Height` returns 32. But, when I tried to re-run it, It returns 0.

Is this supposed to be a bug, or am I doing it wrong?

*Currently using Visual Studio 2017 RC.*

Comment: I test it that it always returns 0. Unless I click the Minimize button or  the Icon on the taskbar, it will return 32.

Comment: Strange. I also got a smilar result like yours. Again, it's not supposed to be happen like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when the code is run, and yes UWP isn't very consistent about it.

What [the docs don't explicitly mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar#system-caption-buttons) is that you need to subscribe to the `coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged` event and then update the height in the callback.  This will account for situations where the size of the title bar changed for some reason.

```
coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += delegate
{
  dragarea.Height = coreTitleBar.Height;
  HamBut.Margin = new Thickness(0, dragarea.Height, 0, 0);
};
```

And it also eliminates the "but it's zero sometimes" problem.